# Store Large Amount of Data (Statistical Data, Log Data) and retrieve it easily

Tags: database, mongodb, statistics, store

I have created an advertising system where the system will collecting the data every second,

For example:

Start Time : 6:00pm 14 Dec 2020

End Time : 6:10pm 14 Dec 2020

RelatedId : 6d32683d71hd3x286s62327hd

The data will be stored every second for each site of viewing, meaning one user view = one-time record, roughly every ten seconds will have 200 new row data insert.

With this amount of data, is there any way to store it properly and could be retrieved easily?

Sample

Given Date range : 1 Jan 2020 to 1 Jan 2021

-retrieve all collected data and generate the report

The amount of time to retrieve the data is too long (cause error frequently) due to the too large amount of data inside the database(billions rows of data)

Summary:

How to store this kind of huge amount of data properly? Any Machanism?

Comment: What do you mean by "store it properly and could be retrieved easily"? If you get 20 records per second, which gives 1.7 million rows per day, how to you get *billions* of rows?

Comment: All the data will be kept, so going through the month or even year there will be billions of rows of data, want to ask anyway to store this kind of large amount of statistical data.

Comment: Ok,, what do you mean by "How to store this kind of data properly"?  For high data volume you may deploy a [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) You need to be more specific.